# How to create editable object mesh for an object made using modifiers

Tags: mesh, modifiers, objects

I want to know how to make I solid mesh to work with when I have used say array modifier to design an object. Because when we use array modifier it just makes the same object visible the number of times we want it to, it does not create a duplicate of it.

Like I have made a chocolate bar by using array modifier but when I switch to edit mode it only shows the 1 editable piece which I made initially not those made by using array modifier.

Can I make the changes permanent like if I created the cheese using spheres and boolean modifier and now after getting my cheese ready is there any way so that I delete the spheres and the cheese remains intact as it was.

Comment: for the first one maybe you can try animation nodes addon and object instancer node. so you make what you need and you can change instances. and i dont think i understood but maybe you can try apply boolean modifiers

Comment: do you want to add a screenshot? I read chocolate bar and then cheese ... huh? Try to apply the array modifier to make the change permanent.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the modifiers to make them permanent/editable. Click the down arrow next to the modifier's name and select "Apply". Then you can edit all your chocolate bars, or delete your sphere cutter objects, or whatever else you want to do with the permanent modifications.

[image: ModifierApply]

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH CHRISTOPHER